# Using differentials to optimize a function

Tags: calculus, optimization, differential, infinitesimals

I've read in a [paper](http://math.oregonstate.edu/bridge/papers/differentials.pdf) by Tevian Dray an alternative way to solve optimization problems manipulating "differentials". Here is an example of how it works (next I quote the paper).

> Consider the problem of minimizing the length of a piecewise straight path connecting two fixed points with a given line, as shown in Figure 1. For instance, the line could represent a river along which a single pumping station is to be built to serve two towns. The distances $C$, $D$, and $S = a + b$ are specified; the goal is to determine $a$ and/or $b$ so that $ℓ = p + q$ is minimized.
>
> The standard solution to this problem involves expressing $a, b, p, q$, and hence $ℓ$, in terms of a single variable, typically $a$, then minimizing $ℓ$ by computing $\frac {dℓ} {da}$ and setting it equal to zero. This computation is straightforward, but involves the derivatives of square roots and some messy algebra.
>
> [image: Figure 1: Minimizing the combined distance p + q between two fixed points and a line]
>
> Consider instead the following solution, using differentials. First, write down what you
>   know:
>   $$a + b = S$$
>   $$a^2 + C^2 = p^2$$
>   $$b^2 + D^2 = q^2$$
>   $$p + q = ℓ$$
>
> where $S, C, D$ are known constants. Next, take the differential of each equation:
>   $$da + db = 0$$
>   $$2a\ da = 2p\ dp$$
>   $$2b\ db = 2q\ dq$$
>   $$dp + dq = dℓ$$
>
> We are trying to minimize $ℓ$, so we set $dℓ = 0$ to obtain
>
> $$0 = dℓ = dp + dq = \frac{a}{p} da + \frac{b}{q} db = \left ( \frac{a}{p} - \frac{b}{q} \right ) da $$
>
> so that
>
> $$\frac{b^2}{a^2}=\frac{q^2}{p^2}=\frac{b^2+D^2}{a^2+C^2}$$
>
> which (since lengths must be positive) quickly yields
>
> $$\frac{b}{a}=\frac{D}{C}$$
>
> so that
>
> $$a =\frac{CS}{C + D}$$ $$b =\frac{DS}{C + D}$$
>
> and it is straightforward to verify that these values do in fact minimize $ℓ$.

I've tried to use this method to solve some problems, and sometimes it works and sometimes doesn't (when I have to optimize a function $f(x,y,z)$ with two constraint function $g_1(x,y,z)=c_1$ and $g_2(x,y,z)=c_2$, generally I have to use Lagrange multipliers because this manipulation of differentials doesn't lead to the correct answer). Also, I've seen this method been used in some thermodynamics textbooks.

So, **my questions are** why this manipulation of differentials is capable to solve optimization problems? When this leads to a wrong answer? Where (a book, video, etc.) can I learn more about this method? (to use it systematically)

---

Note: I've also asked this question on [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/168456/using-differentials-to-optimize-a-function)

Comment: Looks like stuff I used to write in thermodynamics and chemistry classes...

Comment: On page 9 of their paper the authors write: "What are differentials? Our first response to this question is that it doesn’t matter." This means that what is going on in the above quote is pure magic. A "differential" is a mathematical object; but the "differential of an equation" is nonsense.

Comment: So, that means that we arrive to the correct answer (sometimes) by chance? You wouldn't suggest me to use this method?

Comment: @AlexH. Took the words right out of my mouth. Ah,memories,when life was simpler and I didn't have to worry about $\epsilon$-$\delta$ arguments and empty topological spaces...

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Physical scientists say a lot of mathematically nonsensical things,which I understand because I was a chemistry student and realize it's just a tool to them,they're more interested in the empirical findings that result. Still,it's absurdly irresponsible and good physicists know that playing fast and loose with mathematics is a dangerous game that can lead to nonsensical PHYSICAL theories. Look at the insanity that is the string theory craze-where, as Halmos said about Italian algebraic geometry,a counterexample to the theory is considered a beautiful addition to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *should* be able to use it to solve constrained optimization. Let me give you sort of the big-picture overview.

So you know that if $du$ is small compared to $u$ then you can linearize about $u$. When you want to generalize to more variables, you have to do partial derivatives: for example $$ f(x + dx, y + dy, z + dz) \approx f(x,y,z) + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)_{y,z} dx + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)_{x,z} dy + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \right)_{x,y} dz. $$ There is a nice shorthand for this expression using the dot product of the vector $d\vec r = (dx, dy, dz)$ as $$ f(\vec r + d\vec r) \approx f(\vec r) + \nabla f \cdot d\vec r.$$ 
If you calculate it out, the last term here is the "differential" approach that you get above. Your constraints will generate fixed conditions for $d\vec r$,
$$\nabla g_1 \cdot d\vec r = \nabla g_2 \cdot d\vec r = 0.$$

Now we want to find the points $\vec r$ such that, if $d\vec r$ obeys the constraints, then $\nabla f \cdot d\vec r = 0$. There is no reason that I see that this should lead to a wrong answer. In fact, it leads to a matrix solution $$\left[\begin{array}{c}(\nabla f)^T\\(\nabla g_1)^T\\(\nabla g_2)^T\end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{c}dx \\ dy \\ dz\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{array}\right]$$which amounts to looking for a nontrivial kernel of that matrix, which amounts to saying that the vectors are linearly dependent, which says that $\nabla f + \lambda_1 \nabla g_1 + \lambda_1 \nabla g_2 = \nabla (f + \lambda_1 g_1 + \lambda_2 g_2) = 0$, which gives you back exactly the method of Lagrange multipliers! So these are totally equivalent approaches if you do them correctly.

I guess my basic question is, "are you sure that you've been doing partial derivatives correctly when doing constrained optimization?" Because the general idea of trying to do a simultaneous-solution of differential-based equations seems pretty solid to me.

Comment: Uh-isn't this basically what I suggested? It IS considerably more detailed though.

Answer (score 0):

How do differentials of functions behave at critical points? Consider for functions of one variable. The first derivative test says the derivative is 0 at this point. So the total differential would be 0 at all critical points. The result is a system of n linear equations in n unknowns which is homogeneous. Would the usual solution space conditions this establish the general conditions for obtaining critical points by this method? It seems from your example they would. If you rewrite the equation as a system of homogeneous linear equations,you should be able to solve it just like a normal system of linear equations.

Would the determinant of such a system being nonzero be sufficient to establish when a system of differentials can be used to solve for the boundary coefficients so that the desired linear function-in this case,l-is minimized ? **That's** your question to begin with.